# How to replace pandas columns with the same name in to another dataframe?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have the following large pandas dataframe A:

```
A     B    ...   C
cat   cotsco... apple
cat   walmart... google
dog   sears...   google
dog   homemart... amazon
...
fish  walmart... microsoft
```

An pandas dataframe B:

```
A    B ...     D
1.2  0.0  ...  1
3.3  9.1 ...   2
4.5  1.2 ...   5
6.79 1.222 ... 4
...
9.9  1.3 ...   8
```

How can I replace all the columns that have the same name in pandas dataframe A in B?

```
A     B    ...      C     D
cat   cotsco...   apple   1
cat   walmart...  google  2
dog   sears...    google  5
dog   homemart... amazon  4
...
fish  walmart... microsoft 8
```

I know that I can do `df1['D'] = df2['D']`. However, I have 2000 columns like this. Is there another handy way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use assign only:

```
df1['D'] = df2['D']
```

If need add multiple columns with different columns names:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2[df2.columns.difference(df1.columns)]], axis=1)
```

Or:

```
df = df1.join(df2[df2.columns.difference(df1.columns)])
```

Comment: Thanks... I already tried this... However I can not write by hand for all the cases...

Comment: Can you explain why this solution dont work? Thanks.

Comment: The solution doesnt work since I have like 2000 columns like this... I can't write all the 2000 cases by hand.

Comment: With the second one I got: KeyError: `"Index(['A'.......'B'],\n      dtype='object') not in index"`

Comment: oops, I change solution, please check it - first I swap df1.columns with df2.column, sorry. Now it works.